# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service - .Net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use an API to upload a file to s3
I created an aws profile, my IAM has all the roles + permissions required,
when I try the API locally it's working fine,
but in production, it fails to upload and return this message
"Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service"
ps: I'm using .net core 3.0 and my code is in azure (could it be a firewall issue from azure ?)
thanks

Comment: Explain more about "my code is in azure". Instance Metadata is only available inside AWS resources, like EC2 instances, ECS Container, etc. But not in azure.

Comment: then how it's working locally on my machine but it won't work when I run the same code in production? what am I missing here?

Comment: Probably you have a credential in your local machine, that is why it works there. If your production environment is on AWS, you just need to have a role associated with your resource. If your production environment is outside AWS, you need to have a credential configured there.

Comment: i will try it thanks man

Comment: Update : I have the credentials in .aws file in the project solution, so I get them from there, which means that the credentials files do exist also in the production environment,
I still can't get my head around the fact that it's working locally but it fails to upload in production